# Unable to launch ggplot graphs on Kaggle, always get 'Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): attempt to use zero-length variable name Traceback':

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, kaggle

I had my Rmrkdown file running well on Rstudio and got knit to html fine.
And it could also be saved successfully on Kaggle with all R and Notebook options ensured.
It just can show the graphs on Kaggle.  Can help?
My file is here to share https://www.kaggle.com/helenchoi/bellabeat-marketing-for-spring-assignment?scriptVersionId=75128488 , please advise.  Thanks.

Helen

Comment: hi Helen, you kaggle notebook is not accessible. Could you check if it is shared?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi 5CM & Community,  Thanks for your sharing.  You may try these: For Kaggles, https://www.kaggle.com/helenchoi/bellabeat-marketing-for-spring-assignment, or https://www.kaggle.com/helenchoi/bellabeat-marketing-for-spring-assignment?scriptVersionId=75515617  or  for RPubs where I could display the graphs, please try visit https://rpubs.com/chelen/811107